# Python, ROC curve

Tags: python, scikit-learn, roc

I used roc_curve from sklearn.metrics. I see this error:

I have the results of a binary classifier (true_labels ={0,1}). I need to plot the ROC curve. So I wrote:

```py
X, Y, thresholds = sklearn.metrics.roc_curve(true_labels, prediction_scores, pos_label=1)
```

I see this error:

```py
raise ValueError("{0} format is not supported".format(y_type))

ValueError: multilabel-indicator format is not supported
```

Any helps would be appreciated!

Comment: `true_labels` should be a list of integers the same length as `prediction_scores`. `prediction_scores` contains the score of a classification (floating point values probably between `0` and `1`) and `true_labels` contain the ground truth labels (each entry should be either `0` or `1`).

Comment: @ jodag They are in the way you said. Both true_labels and prediction_scores are numpy.ndarray. Would that be the problem?

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem. My guess is that they have an extra dimension or something then. Can you check `true_labels.shape` and `prediction_scores.shape`?

Comment: @jodag Yes! That was the problem. It's working now. Will you post your answer so that I can accept and rate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments it seems your problem is extra dimensions on your arrays. You can remove the unitary dimensions by applying `numpy.squeeze` to the input arrays before passing them into `roc_curve`. If you know that it's just extra unitary dimensions you can use the `ravel` method to view your arrays as 1d arrays.